# How to position background-image between two texts

Tags: html, css

I want to position a text and image like this:

[image]

This is what I have now

http://jsfiddle.net/vzovk7xd/

```
<section class="feature">
   <div class="container">
       <article class="feature-item design">
          <h2>Web Design</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus, lacus ac commodo volutpat, felis odio pulvinar enim, non dapibus mauris nulla sed ipsum.</p>
           <a href="">READ MORE</a>
       </article>
       <article class="feature-item media">
          <h2>Social Media</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus, lacus ac commodo volutpat, felis odio pulvinar enim, non dapibus mauris nulla sed ipsum.</p>
           <a href="">READ MORE</a>
       </article>
       <article class="feature-item apps">
          <h2>Mobile Apps</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus, lacus ac commodo volutpat, felis odio pulvinar enim, non dapibus mauris nulla sed ipsum.</p>
           <a href="">READ MORE</a>
       </article>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.feature {
margin-top: 100px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
}
.feature-item {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
.design {
    background: url(https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b0a905e3eb32_128.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: The images have the same height and width?

Comment: Why a background image? Just put the image inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set background image to your .design div, put another div between the heading and paragraph, give it width and height, and set background image to that div.

```
<article class="feature-item design">
    <h2>Web Design</h2>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus, lacus ac commodo volutpat, felis odio pulvinar enim, non dapibus mauris nulla sed ipsum.</p>
    <a href="">READ MORE</a>
</article>
```

css

```
.image { width: 100%; height: 140px; background: url(https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b0a905e3eb32_128.png) no-repeat center center; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzovk7xd/1/

Answer (score 0):

add this css:

```
.design, .media, .apps  {
background: url(https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b0a905e3eb32_128.png) no-repeat top center;
background-position:75px 90px;
}

.feature-item p {margin-top:200px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzovk7xd/6/

Answer (score 0):

You try to put an **inline** (in the elments flow order) element with the **background** style (out of the elements flow)... Better use an inline element to present it like an inline element.

**Solution A**: (modify CSS, remove background)

```
.feature-item h2:after {
    content: url('https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b0a905e3eb32_128.png');
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzovk7xd/9/

[image]

**Solution B**: (modify HTML)

```
 <article class="feature-item design">
     <h2>Web Design</h2>
     <figure></figure>


figure {
    background: url(https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b0a905e3eb32_128.png) 
                no-repeat center center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzovk7xd/3/

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it as background (if you want to do that, you need to set width and height for .design box).. instead, add another div element between h2 and p elmenets:

```
 <h2>Web Design</h2>
 <div class="design"><img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b0a905e3eb32_128.png"/></div>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzovk7xd/7/

[image]